# Getting Exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: uitextview, nsexception

I am getting Exception for substringWithRange:range in  below method.

I am having textview with editing disabled.

i am using textfield only for text selection.
when i am selecting text for firs time no exception but when i press for second time it throughs.

Exception: 
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

NSRange range = [tv selectedRange];
str = [tv.text substringWithRange:range];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked your example. Sometimes you retrieve an undefined range like (2147483647, 0). So, check it to avoid crashes:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSRange range = [textView selectedRange];
    if(range.length == 0 || range.location > textView.text.length)
        return;

    NSString *str = [textView.text substringWithRange:range];
}
```